# How to format JupyterLab notebook settings to auto-indent in appropriate spots when writing R code

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm using R in JupyterLab. Whenever I create functions with ggplot, JupyterLab does not auto-indent my script after the '+' operator. The same holds for when I'm piping: JupyterLab does not auto-indent my script after the '%>%' operator.

What could I do to change this? Is there, perhaps, a GitHub repository out there with a catalog of user settings to make R behave more like it does in RStudio - but in JupyterLab?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but the way I handle this is using the following notation:

```
(
    ggplot(data)
    + geom_line()
    + geom_point()
)
```

This way:

- you can comment out `+ geom_point()` at any time by only adding `#` (if the `+` is at the end, you would need to remove it from previous line)
- you get consistent auto-indent
- if you decide to assign the plot to a variable, changing the variable name does not shift the `ggplot(data)` line (so there is no cascading effect on line length)

As for why it behaves like that when using pipe/plus at the end: it comes down to choices made in [CodeMirror R mode](https://codemirror.net/5/mode/r/). JupyterLab 4 is migrating to CodeMirror 6 which may offer more advanced parsing system, but it currently re-uses the old R mode from CodeMirror 5 - so there is a potential for improvements, but someone would need to undertake some fundamental work first. There is an issue about supporting it in CodeMirror 5 here: https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror5/issues/6671 (but it is unlikely to get fixed since the new development focuses on CodeMirror 6).

As for more other R-specific features, you may be interested in:

- [Map keyboard shortcut to code snippet in Jupyter Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440087/map-keyboard-shortcut-to-code-snippet-in-jupyter-lab/67149446#67149446)
- [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp) with [R languageserver](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver).

Comment: (of course it could be addressed in CodeMirror 5 mode if you have time to fix that issue/pay someone to do so and the maintainer agrees - it is just my feeling is that they prioritise CM6 now)